# How to Change from generic ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu-Studio

Tags: synaptic, cd

I just purchased my first notebook, BA10, from Tuxedo Linux and it is lacking a CD-DVD-BLURAY, but is loaded with generic Ubuntu 20.04. There are 3 PPA's from Tuxedo loaded but I want the latest Ubuntu-Studio which is not offered by Tuxedo. I don't want to download an ISO to burn or use a thumb drive if I don't have to. Can I use Synaptic Package Manager? Or do I have to get an external CD/DVD drive or use a thumb drive? I cannot walk, so I want a band in my house...I've been dreaming 52 years for something like this to happen. Now there is more than just me and my handmade from scraps Strat to make music. Would love Xfce too, if it's available. Thanks, Cheers,

George

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and Ubuntu Studio are technically both Ubuntu.  The use the same package repositories.

**You can just use the software center to install the packages that you need.**

Don't add a PPA unless you are prepared to take that [risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for) into your own hands.

If you want to go so far as to change the desktop environment to something like XFCE, it would be better that you reinstall the operating system.

Changing desktop environments is not a good task for someone that is not already highly experienced with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu studio is basically most of a collection of software that all artists use.  You probably only want a few software that meet your needs, which you can install from software center and not have a brunch of software you don't need or want.

Comment: As I mentioned, there are 3 PPA's already there from Tuxedo, if I change to Synaptic, those PPA's will still be there and I don't want to get 2 sets of updates or other conflicts which always seem to haunt me. I could delete the PPA's, I don't know if that would affect my warranty or not. The hard drive is full with the generic Ubuntu. It came with a pen-drive that will restore the box to it's original factory installation, but I want to put 3 or 4 distro's on like my old boxes

Comment: Why would deleting a PPA void any kind of warranty?  It's your device, right?  You can put whatever software you want on it.  That being said, know that PPAs are unofficial software.  Literally any Tom Dick or Harry can create an account and upload a PPA.  If the package exists in `apt` or the software center, I would strongly advise *against* the PPA version, unless the PPA version is a newer version that contains some feature that you absolutely must have and are willing to risk unstable potentially unsafe software by using the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

One safe way: The "tasksel" tool.

1. `sudo apt install tasksel`
2. Open Tasksel (`sudo tasksel`)

   - Tip: Use the arrow keys and TAB key to navigate, NOT your mouse
   - **Un-select** "Ubuntu Desktop"  (Tip: Use the spacebar to select/unselect)
   - **Select** "Ubuntu Studio desktop"
   - Optional: **Select** "Xubuntu desktop" also
   - Tab to <OK> and hit Enter
3. Go make a sandwich while the system changes out hundreds of packages.

   - Your username and paswsword will be the same
   - Your data in /home will be untouched

If you want to change back, simply run tasksel again.

Comment: This will technically work, but I would not call it "safe".  If there's an issue with any one of those "hundred of packages" that are changed out, it could result in a bad time for OP.  And it might not be successful to just change it back.

Comment: I'm afraid the PPA's that Tuxedo installed will interfere with updates that may come from another repository that Taskel inserts. Worst scenario, I insert an FAI pen and start over. My hard drive is full, I guess I should just get an external CD/DVD, burn an ISO and partition my hard drive.